# Подгрузка скрытых блоков

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть некоторое количество блоков **content**. Например:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при загрузке сайта были показаны например первые 4 блока, а остальные были скрыты ***display: none;*** пока не нажмешь на кнопку "Показать еще"? После нажатия на кнопку открывались еще 4 блока, потом еще и т.д...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/vetw63ww/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильнее вставить только 4 элемента, остальное добавлять, а не скрывать.
Но если уж такая структура...
Найти все блоки в массив, срез больше шага - `display: none;`, слушать кнопку, при клике брать срез от текущего элемента до текущий элемент + шаг и открывать их.

```js
let data = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .content')),
    step = 4,
    item = 0;

data.slice(step).forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none');
item += step;

document.querySelector('#more').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let tmp = data.slice(item, item + step);
  tmp.forEach(e => e.style.display = 'block');
  item += step;
  
  if(tmp.length < 4)
    this.remove();
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="content">Content 1</div>
 <div class="content">Content 2</div>
 <div class="content">Content 3</div>
 <div class="content">Content 4</div>
 <div class="content">Content 5</div>
 <div class="content">Content 6</div>
 <div class="content">Content 7</div>
 <div class="content">Content 8</div>
 <div class="content">Content 9</div>
 <div class="content">Content 10</div>
    <input type='button' id='more' value='Show me more!' />
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Возможно еще сделать так что бы кнопка MORE исчезала если больше нечего показывать?

Comment: Конечно, обновил пример.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, это то что надо.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var c = $(".content").size();
  x = 4;
  $('.content:lt(' + x + ')').fadeIn();
  $('.btn-more').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x = (x + 4 <= c) ? x + 4 : c;
    $('.content:lt(' + x + ')').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="btn-more">btn more</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Возможно еще сделать так что бы кнопка MORE исчезала если больше нечего показывать?